# VB.NET: Creating an event with members

Tags: vb.net, events, eventargs

Currently I have defined an event like this:

```
Public Event SoundCompleted(ByVal uGUID As String, ByVal uPath As String, ByVal uStatus As Integer)
```

I would like to ask how I can put all these 3 variables into one variable as Microsoft does with the "e." events.

I would like to have something like this:

```
Public Event SoundCompleted(Byval e As SoundCompletedArgs)
```

but I don't know how this is done.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I just need to create a new class for the eventargs.